# Does Dodge have a cap?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am playing monk and I would like to evaluate a dodge build but I have a doubt. Probably 100% dodge cannot be reached and it should be a cap somewhere.

I searched through different forums and there are really different opinions that goes from 50% to 85%. I would like to know a more precise value, can you help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, dodge from abilities is multiplicative and not additive. For example: when you have 25% dodge on your monk from just dexterity, and enable the [Mantra of Evasion](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/mantra-of-evasion), it will not actually add a flat 15% to your dodge, it will only add 11.3% dodge (rounded up). This is because it multiplies by the remaining number, which in this case is 75. With Mantra of Evasion still enabled you can try dual welding with the [Guardian's Path](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/passive/the-guardians-path) passive. It will then multiply your current remaining number: 63.7 by 15%, now giving you 9.6%(9.555~) instead of 15% for a total dodge of 45.9%(45.855~).

Additionally, based on these [calculations](http://armadagaming.com/showthread.php?459-Armor-Resistances-and-Effective-Health&p=4260&viewfull=1#post4260): You will be able to max out your dodge by stacking 8000 dexterity. I doubt this is achievable in game, but you may be able to get close with an unrealistic amount of dexterity...

So, it appears that there is a cap because it will be very hard to reach 100% with such mechanics.

Comment: don't forget the fists of thunder rune to add 16% dodge.  You can alternate that with crippling wave to keep the attack-speed and reduced damage buffs on your target.

Comment: Your link on `calculations` has expired.

Comment: Currently the monks with the highest DPS in the game, who all stack Dex heavily, have < 3500 Dex, so 8k is still a long way off, even at Paragon (1.0) level 100.