# Is there any guaranteed way to complete the Like Water achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements, diablo-iii-monk

The Like Water Achievement Monk Class specific achievement requires you to dodge 15 attacks in a row.

[Dodge is a percentage chance with diminishing returns as I understand it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67995/23580). I boost my Dex quite high when I can and even using Mantra of Evasion, Fists of Thunder, Sixth Sense and Guardian's Path with 2 1-H weapons I still can't seem to get 15 consecutive dodges.

Am I doing something wrong? Does enemy level vs. your level make a difference to dodge chance? Is there any way to increase dodge that I am missing? Is my Dex maybe too low and if so, how high would it need to be to get this achievement? **In short, how do I get the Like Water achievement?**

Specific details on the minimum setup needed would be much appreciated if relevant. Extra points for math as well.

Comment: Guardian's Path with a 2-H weapon adds Spirit Regeneration, not Dodge. Use Dual-Wield.

Comment: @Domocus good catch, typo'd. Still thinking about [the last answer I posted](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68878/is-my-spirit-or-any-other-ability-resource-rounded-up-down/68903#68903). I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to receive this achievement via the Serenity skill.  There's no combat log, so I can't double-check, I'm afraid. I was in the middle of a pretty large group of enemies and losing health.  As I always do, I hit Serenity and kept going.  When Serenity wore off, I received the achievement.

I'm not 100% sure, but I didn't see a lot of dodge indicators while Serenity was active.  Perhaps it triggers on just not taking damage from attacks?

Comment: I seldom use serenity except when I'm hunting for something like "kill so and so without taking damage" achievement. Will test this promptly.

Comment: I don't think its Serenity.... I use that skill constantly and have definitely been "hit" over 15 times in a row with it active, and have never gotten this achievement

Comment: It's certainly possible to get the achievement with Serenity up, but it is by no means guaranteed. It seems the game still checks for a dodge before letting the attack through to be absorbed by Serenity.

Comment: Level 60, 43.5% chance to dodge. Go to the Royal Crypt (Act I). Pop Serenity w/4 second duration rune. First attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my guess.  Level to 60, get a lot of dex, then go somewhere with a ridiculous number of small monsters early in act I (spider cave?).  You can take the hits if they hit you, so try running around spamming evasion.

Also, try standing in those things that breath fire near the end of Act 3 - I find I dodge those a lot, and they might count.

I'm not sure if it's true, but I suspect just based on playing that your dodge chance might increase if you're moving, so try that too.

Comment: In D2, your dodge percent actually went to 0 when running. I believe they removed that for D3, but I don't know about that assumption.

Comment: @Wikwocket In D3 that was definitely nerfed (I've dodged while moving).  Should be easy to figure out if it goes up or down while moving though.

Answer (score 2):

Serenity helps you by stopping all the attacks that aren't dodged. Got it on my 2nd try with serenity at Iskatu. I spent 15 minutes not using Serenity before that, not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

## Handy Step-by-step Guide

1. Level Up (probably at least to 50).
2. Load up on Dexterity gear (make sure there is 0 thorns damage).
   *At this point, you should have a **chance to dodge of about 50%.***
3. Equip Mantra of Evasion (no rune) and Serenity (duration rune) as skills.
4. Fight Iskatu (first battle in Act IV).
5. Pop Mantra of Evasion.
6. Let the Shadow Vermin swarm you.
7. Pop Serenity

This worked for my wife.

Answer (score 0):

Serenity works fine.  Go to the first quest of Normal Act 4 and put it on.  It will take you no time at all.

Comment: serenity just absorbs hits that you don't dodge.  If you're having trouble staying alive while trying to be hit, feel free to use it. If you watch, some attacks are dodges and others are absorbed, which likely means it has no effect on dodge %

Answer (score 0):

Use abilties like the dodge mantra, crit to dodge % passive, and dual wielding dodge bonus, and then spam the dodge mantra while tanking lower level creeps.

Get rid of any thorns-stat gear you might have on you, it took me five minutes to get the chain of fifteen.